# What is the meaning and function of 'accepted' answer in English Language & Usage forum?

Tags: discussion

I'm with English Language & Usage forum almost three months, but still not clear about the difference between 'Up-vote' and 'Accepted' answer. What does come up when I click Check (Accepted) mark vis-a-vis Up vote mark?

Answer (score 6):

It means this:

> I, as the question owner, found this particular answer most helpful for *my* needs.

It is not *required*. We view it as more of a social convention than anything else.

Note that it also has a few effects:

- gives answerer +15 rep, gives you +2 rep
- "docks" the answer to the top of the answer list regardless of sort order